# Draw a box every 45 minutes in pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I want to draw boxes that cover 45-minute periods in Pinescript, but due to the limitations of this language, and my unfamiliarity with it, I am struggling.

This is the code that I wrote; it's drawing the box but it's only one box. I want to partition the chart into 45-minute segments.

my code:

```
indicator("box", overlay=true)


anchorTime = input.time(timestamp("23 Aug 2023 13:30"), "Date")
anchorBarIndex = (time - anchorTime) / (1000 * timeframe.in_seconds(timeframe.period))
anchorBarsBack = bar_index - anchorBarIndex 


next_candle = anchorTime + (45 * 60000) 
next_candle_back = (time - next_candle) / (1000 * timeframe.in_seconds(timeframe.period))
next_candle_bar = bar_index - next_candle_back 

box.new(anchorBarsBack, high, next_candle_bar, low, border_color = color.red, bgcolor = color.new(color.silver, 60))
```

Answer (score 1):

This calculation is off:

```
anchorBarIndex = (time - anchorTime) / (1000 * timeframe.in_seconds(timeframe.period))
anchorBarsBack = bar_index - anchorBarIndex
```

Your `anchorBarIndex` is increased by 1 on each bar. By its nature, `bar_index` is also increased by 1 on each bar. So, `anchorBarsBack` is always the same.

Because of that, you actually draw MANY boxes on the same bar.

[image]

You can actually use something like:

```
is_new_45 = timeframe.change("45")
```

to detect if it is a new 45-min bar. Then draw your box conditionally using that variable.